# Inductive proof to $P(A_i) = \frac a N$ - a question about probability

Tags: probability, induction

> Consider a population comprising of $N (≥ 2)$ units out of which $a (\in \{1, 2, . . . , N −
> 1\})$ are labeled as $S$ (success) and $N − a$ are labeled as $F$ (failure). A sample of
> size $n (\in \{1, 2, . . . , N − 1\})$ is drawn from this population, drawing one unit at a
> time and without replacing it back into the population (i.e., sampling is without
> replacement). Let $A_i (i = 1, 2, . . . , n)$ denote the probability of obtaining success
> $(S)$ in the $i$-th trial. Show that $P(A_i) = \frac a N$, where $i = 1,2,...,n$.

My idea is to use induction on $n$, and I need help completing the solution. It'd be great if you can share any other ideas.

The base case is trivial, i.e. $P(A_1) = \frac a N$. For $P(A_2)$, we do
$$P(A_2) = P(A_2 \cap A_1) + P(A_2\cap A_1^c) = \frac{N-a}{N}\cdot \frac{a}{N-1} + \frac{a}{N} \cdot\frac{a-1}{N-1} = \frac a N$$
I want to extend a similar idea to the induction step. Suppose $P(A_i) = \frac a N$ for $1\le i \le k-1$. Then,
$$P(A_{k}) = P(A_k \cap A_{k-1}) + P(A\cap A_{k-1}^c) = P(A_k|A_{k-1})P(A_{k-1}) + P(A_k|A_{k-1}^c)P(A_{k-1}^c)$$
How do I use the induction hypothesis to find $P(A_k|A_{k-1})$ and $P(A_k|A_{k-1}^c)$? Please help me complete this or suggest other ideas!

Comment: There are exactly $N$ units and each of them has equal chances to become the unit that is drawn at the $i$-th trial. Further $a$ of them are labeled as a success. Then the probability on a success at the $i$-th trial is $\frac{a}{N}$, i.e. the number of favourable outcomes divided by the number of possible outcomes. There is no need to go for a proof in which induction is used.

Answer (score 1):

"....or suggest other ideas!..."

---

Label the units with $1,2,\dots,N$ in such a way that those with the labels $1,2,\dots,a$ are the successes.

For fixed $i\in\{1,\dots,N\}$ let $E_j$ denote the event that the unit with label $j$ is drawn as $i$-th unit.

Then: $$A_i=\bigcup_{j=1}^aE_j$$and consequently:$$P(A_i)=P\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^aE_j\right)=\sum_{j=1}^aP(E_j)=aP(E_1)=\frac{a}{N}$$